# Exponential map for symplectic manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M, \omega)$ be a symplectic manifold. Darboux's theorem states that, for any point $p \in M$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $p$, a neighborhood $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ of $0$, and a symplectomorphism $(U, \omega) \cong (V, \omega_\mathrm{std})$. I'm curious whether the following stronger statement would be true: does there exist an "exponential map"
$$
\exp : T M \to M
$$
where for all $p \in M$, the map
$$
\exp_p := \exp|_{T_p M} : (T_p M, \omega_p) \to (M, \omega)
$$
preserves the symplectic structure in a neighborhood of the origin? (In other words, $\exp_p$ restricts to a Darboux chart for all $p \in M$.)

Comment: Of course you can define such a map, it is essentially a local problem, when $M$ is, say, a round ball in $R^{2n}$.

Comment: Some argument would be needed to show that these local definitions glue right?

Comment: Do you want to know the proof, or do you just need a reference?

Comment: You can use a partition of unity plus a parameteric form of the Darboux theorem, cf. my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3716083/when-does-darbouxs-theorem-on-symplectic-manifolds-work-globally/3722177#3722177)

Comment: @ArcticChar A reference is good.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks!